# jQuery: Click Outside Div to Close It; Get Rid of Highlights

Tags: jquery, click

Here's my page: http://frankjuval.com/web/playground/jQpage/index.html

1. I want to be able to click outside the popup divs (i.e. video 1, video 2, video 3) and have them close.
2. For some reason, when you click on the areas of the image map, there's a blue highlight. How do I get rid of that?

Just FYI, I'm using "`function(e){ e.preventDefault();`" in order to stop the page from shifting when the popup div opens.

That's it.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="page">

    <div id="map">
        <img src="images/content_transparency.png" alt="all_content" width="1324" usemap="#3dmap">
    <map id="3dmap" name="3dmap">
        <area id="graphic1" shape="rect" coords="271,811,561,1208" href="#video1" />
        <area id="graphic2" shape="circle" coords="646,910,55" href="#video2" />
        <area id="graphic3" shape="rect" coords="711,898,1016,1204" href="#video3" />
        <area shape="default" nohref="nohref" title="Default" alt="Default"/>
    </map>
    </div><!-- END MAP -->

    <div id="video1" style="display: none;">
        <img src="images/video1.png" alt="video-Overlay_IOA" width="624">
    </div>

    <div id="video2" style="display: none;">
        <img src="images/video2.png" alt="video-Overlay_HE" width="624">
    </div>

    <div id="video3" style="display: none;">
        <img src="images/video3.png" alt="video-Overlay_USF" width="624">
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.page {
  background: #000 url(../images/PainterlyWater_02.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;

}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.page {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
}
#map {
    width: 1020px;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;

}
#map img {
    display: block;
    margin: auto auto auto -17px;

}

#video1,
#video2,
#video3 {
    width: 624px;
    height: 477px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 18%;
    left: 36%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

jQuery (within the HTML page):

```
$(function(){

// VIDEO 1
$("#graphic1").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
      $("#video1").fadeToggle(400);
      $(this).toggleClass("active");
      });

      $( "#video1" ).click(function() {
      $( "#video1" ).hide()
      });

// VIDEO 2
$("#graphic2").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
      $("#video2").fadeToggle(400);
      $(this).toggleClass("active");
      });

      $( "#video2" ).click(function() {
      $( "#video2" ).hide()
      });

// VIDEO 2
$("#graphic3").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
      $("#video3").fadeToggle(400);
      $(this).toggleClass("active");
      });

      $( "#video3" ).click(function() {
      $( "#video3" ).hide()
      });


});
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of `e.preventDefault();` use `e.stopPropagation()` to stop the document event to trigger it. **note**: `.preventDefault()` is only used when you don't want the page from redirecting when you click on a link or submit button.